# Правильна ли следующая форма написания?

Tags: стилистика, предлоги

Услуга предоставляется со всеми тарифными планами.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не совсем точное выражение: из него можно понять, что и тарифные планы тоже "предоставляются" в распоряжение клиента или ещё как-то. Лучше "при выборе" (клиентом) или "в рамках" (любого тарифного плана).